# removing validation attributes conditionally

Tags: asp.net, validation

i have a panel which iam showing as pop up with few textbox controls with several validation controls and button on clicking which i am checking for validation now i want to add a checkbox on checking it it should disable some of the controls and remove the validation properties from them and on unchecking it apply the same i am able to make those controls disabled but still on clicking that button it is asking for validating those controls

on the click event of checkbox i am calling one javascript function and applying the disabled attribute to some of the controls

```
function disableOtherElements(e)
{
    var id = e.checked;
    if (id)
    {
        $('.dd').attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('.dd').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```

dd is the class assigned to all the controls that i want to be disabled.
what i have to do to remove the validation properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve that would be to use the [client-side API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) exposed by the ASP.NET validators.

First, you'll have to iterate over `Page_Validators` to locate all the validators that target your elements, then use `ValidatorEnable()` to enable or disable validation:

```
function enableValidation(element, enable)
{
    $.each(Page_Validators, function() {
        if (this.controltovalidate == element.id) {
            ValidatorEnable(this, enable);
        }
    });
}

function disableOtherElements(e)
{
    if (e.checked) {
        $('.dd').each(function() {
            enableValidation(this, false);
        }).attr('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('.dd').each(function() {
            enableValidation(this, true);
        }).removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}
```